# Why isnt the mail I sent through SendGrid visible in my sent items? (.net core)

Tags: c#, azure, email, sendgrid

I tried sending mails with the help of send grid mail service using .Net core.

```
var client = new SendGridClient(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
var from = new EmailAddress("test@abc.com", "Not User");
var subject = "TestMail";
var to = new EmailAddress("test@abc.com, "Example User");
var plainTextContent = "This is body";
var htmlContent = "";
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Wait();
```

The mails sent using this code are not visible in sent items of my mail box. What is the possible solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a viable solution for this, the BCC one doesn't seem correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the email it uses SMTP directly to sendgrid. When you send via Google they will automatically add it to your outbox. To do the same when someone else sends the message you would have to manually place a copy of the sent message in your outbox using IMAP.

> What is the possible solution to this?

You could use SendGrid's [BCC option](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/mail/#bcc) will allow you to BCC an email address, in this case your mail account, with every email sent.

Go to your `SendGrid Account`>`Manage`>`Settings`>`Mail Settings` and turn on the `BCC` option.

[image]

**Note**: With this setting turned on, you will be charged an extra email for every email you send. So reclick on `Manage` and you will see the popup message.

Here is Send mailbox snapshot:

[image]